# How to change text and icon colour of KivyMD’s Bottom Navigation

Tags: python, android, ios, user-interface, kivy

I have tried to follow the [documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/bottom-navigation/index.html) for this widget:
`text_color_normal`
and
`text_color_active` but they don’t work. :/

Can someone please help me :’)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the only solution is to use ThemeManager.

> main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

class Main(MDApp):
    """docstring for Main"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.screen     = Screen()
        self.sm         = ScreenManager()
        self.theme_cls  = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        #Enter the desired color instead of red
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main().run()
```

> main.kv

```
Screen:
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: 'home_screen'

            MDBottomNavigation:
                panel_color: rgba('262626')
                MDBottomNavigationItem:
                    icon: 'home'
                    text: 'home'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also navigate to kivymd/uix then open bottom navigation. py and customize text_color on line 273 and 289 for icon and label to your desired color eg, 1,1,1,1